# Jabber server - ejabberd or jabberd2?

Tags: software-recommendation, jabber, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm going to run my own jabber server on my Ubuntu server.

Should I use rather `ejabberd` or `jabberd2` daemon?
Which of them is better?
What are the differences between them?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/101865/jabberd2-vs-ejabberd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends very much on your needs. What are your expectations? [General comparison is available on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software)

If you're just looking for a simple xmpp server for your private server, I would recommend [Prosody](http://prosody.im/). It's lightweight, easy to configure, supports SSL, and has a helpful community. You can get it up and running literally in minutes.

Comment: Vote up for Prosody, thanks. I'll give it a try, hadn't known about it before...